# Operation on list and lists inside a dictionary

Tags: python

I have some data which is basically in the form of lists and I want to calculate the standard deviation.

1. I have calculated the mean values of the data arrays and placed them in a separate list. Now to calculate the standard deviation, I am required to subtract first mean value from all the data points in the first list, take a square, and so on.
2. For the second mean value, the same operation should be performed on the second list in the dictionary and similarly for the last value as well.
3. These operations should give me a list with three elements corresponding to the standard deviation with respective mean values.

Here is a code I tried to implement but this code gives me nine values because it iterates through all three lists for each mean value but I want to iterate through the first list for the first mean value, the second list for the second mean value and so on. what changes do I need to make it work as I desire?

```
mean = [3,4,8]

data = {'a': [1,3,5], 
        'b': [2,4,6], 
        'c': [7,8,9]
       }

std_variation = []
for element in mean:
    variation = 0
    for value in data.values():
        for inner_element in value:
            variation += (inner_element - element)**2
        variation = variation/(len(value)-1)
        std_variation.append(round(variation,2)**0.5)
print(output)
```

Comment: It would be better if you format your question using paras/bullets/lists. It is difficult to read a wall of text.

Comment: Don't implement this calculation yourself. There are libraries that will do it for you. Google "python standard deviation" for details. The only part you will need to implement is iterating over the dictionary.

Comment: If you absolutely must implement this yourself without using a library, look at `zip()`. This allows you to iterate over the means and data in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy` as Ann Zen shows. Or if you don't want to install a third-party package, you can use the `statistics` module:

```
from statistics import std

lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(std(lst))
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a function [`std`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiH2Z6A1vrpAhV_TTABHYx3Au8QFjAAegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.scipy.org%2Fdoc%2Fnumpy%2Freference%2Fgenerated%2Fnumpy.std.html&usg=AOvVaw2HOCeveQ53AzBzOoFHnkCY) built into `numpy` that will find the standard deviation of a given array:

```
import numpy as np

lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(np.std(lst))
```

Output:

```
2.581988897471611
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Ann Zen and the Code-Apprentice show, you can import `statistics` or `numpy` to calculate the standard deviation. Here is how you could calculate it yourself. Your issue is you are looping through through each list of values in `data` for every mean value. Instead, you want to loop through the mean value and the corresponding list of values in the same loop. You can do this with the [`zip()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip) function. Here is one way of fixing your code. Hope this helps!

```
mean_list = [3,4,8]

data = {'a': [1,3,5],
        'b': [2,4,6],
        'c': [7,8,9]
       }

st_dev_list = []

for mean, values in zip(mean_list, data.values()):
    variance = 0
    n = len(values)
    for value in values:
        variance += (value - mean) ** 2
    variance /= n
    std_dev = variance ** 0.5
    st_dev_list.append(round(std_dev, 2))
print(st_dev_list)
```